# ['type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I use command react-native init "name project" then open vscode appear to have error message code. (image)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [js 'types' can only be used in a .ts file - Visual Studio Code using @ts-check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859169/js-types-can-only-be-used-in-a-ts-file-visual-studio-code-using-ts-check)

Comment: The auto-generated sample project itself had this issue, I wonder why the developers of react-native or VS Code would do such a thing

Answer (score 68):

This is what you need to do with VS Code, observe the gif carefully

```
Steps to resolve error
1. Go to extension
2. Click on more (...) and select Show Built-in extension
3. Search "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" - yellow & blue icon
4. Click on Setting icon of extension and select Disable (workspace)
5. Click on Reload / Restart Required
```

[image]

Comment: This is the strangest top-most voted answer I've seen in stackoverflow. What's next, we link youtube videos with tutorials? The suggested solution can be explained in text with:

1. Search in extensions for: `@builtin typescript-language-features`
2. Disable extensions for the workspace

*That said* Disabling this, and not replacing it with something else that doesn't have this issue is not a good idea.

Comment: The point is not about video or audio or gif or text. It is about how easily and quickly your idea can be explained clearly. If stackoverflow encourages embedding short youtube videos to make it more clear, then why not.

Comment: +1 I appreciate the gif - makes it clear what to do without having to read annoying text. ;) However, search engines are going to index a text explanation much better than a gif, so while the gif is helpful, it probably should be accompanied with text explaining the steps.

Comment: This solution disables intellisense for your workspace, it's best to use C2P1 solution [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/631)

Answer (score 24):

If you are getting this in React Native its probably a known bug in VSCode, that when Google Flow (which competes with MS Typescript) is coded, shows errors erroneously mentioning Typescript.

Your current .js code is supposed to be preprocessed by Flow into another .js file with "proper" js.

So make sure [Flow is installed](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode) and then disable the Typescript parsing support. Here's the official answer on the Flow installation webpage:

> Set javascript.validate.enable option to false or completely disable
>   the built-in TypeScript extension for your project (see gif below)...

Otherwise, you may want to stay as is and just change your code as suggested by C2P1 on March 19, 2018 on [the github issue 631](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/631)

To disable the [js] parser (connected to Typescript),

In VSCode menu: `File -> Preferences -> User settings`, (or `ctrl+,`) and add the following line

```
"javascript.validate.enable": false,
```

This answer was completed after seeing Idan Dagan's answer (Not the accepted answer) here: [js 'types' can only be used in a .ts file - Visual Studio Code using @ts-check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859169/js-types-can-only-be-used-in-a-ts-file-visual-studio-code-using-ts-check)

And [here's an excellent albeit old page about setting up the react-native environment, from Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/configure-eslint-prettier-and-flow-in-vs-code-for-react-development-c9d95db07213). (You also have the VSCode React-native-full plugin)

Comment: Its not recommended to disable all java-script validation `"javascript.validate.enable": false,`

Comment: BTW, Flow it is not Google, but Facebook

Answer (score 15):

Just disable built-in extension for TypeScript in VSCode. On the VSCode Extensions choose "**Show Built-in Extensions**" and then search for "**TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features**", Click disable then reload the VSCode. It works for me

Answer (score 4):

In VScode

Press

> CTRL + SHIFT + P

Use this command

> Open User Settings

copy and paste the next line in the search bar in settings

> @ext:vscode.typescript-language-features

ready uncheck JavaScript validation

[image]

Comment: typescript continue working but only in .TS

Answer (score 2):

Helped me to resolve

To disable the [js] parser (connected to Typescript),

In VSCode menu: File -> Preferences -> User settings, (or ctrl+,) and add the following line

"javascript.validate.enable": false,

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for. Unfortunately I haven't Googled a proper solution but we have to disable some JS checking.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/631

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this with a plugin for VSCode "Flow Language Support". It will control the errors of the code instead of the plug-in TS-JS (built-in plugin of VS Code). In Details of plugin, guides you how to disable the original plugin TS-JS VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

instead of disabling **Typescript and Javascript language features** extension, you can go to the extension settings, find the option **Javascript > Validate: Enable**, and uncheck it to remove any warnings.

[image]